# PHP - mongodb client - skip and limit usage

Tags: php, mongodb, profiling

May be this is a silly question, but anyway I have the doubt.

Please take a look at this query:

```
db.posts.find({ "blog": "myblog", 
                "post_author_id": 649, 
                "shares.total": { "$gt": 0 } })
        .limit(10)
        .skip(1750)
        .sort({ "shares.total": -1, "tstamp_published": -1 });
```

actually I see into the mongodb profiler this report:

```
mongos> db.system.profile.find({ nreturned : { $gt : 1000 } }).limit(10).sort( { millis : 1 } ).pretty();
{
    "ts" : ISODate("2013-04-04T13:28:08.906Z"),
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "mydb.posts",
    "query" : {
        "$query" : {
            "blog" : "myblog",
            "post_author_id" : 649,
            "shares.total" : {
                "$gt" : 0
            }
        },
        "$orderby" : {
            "shares.total" : -1,
            "tstamp_published" : -1
        }
    },
    "ntoreturn" : 1760,
    "nscanned" : 12242,
    "scanAndOrder" : true,
    "nreturned" : 1760,
    "responseLength" : 7030522,
    "millis" : 126,
    "client" : "10.0.232.69",
    "user" : ""
}
```

Now the question is: why mongodb is returning 1760 documents when I have explicitly asked to skip 1750?

This is my current Mongodb version, in cluster/sharding.

```
mongos> db.runCommand("buildInfo")
{
    "version" : "2.0.2",
    "gitVersion" : "514b122d308928517f5841888ceaa4246a7f18e3",
    "sysInfo" : "Linux bs-linux64.10gen.cc 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41",
    "versionArray" : [
        2,
        0,
        2,
        0
    ],
    "bits" : 64,
    "debug" : false,
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now the question is: why mongodb is returning 1760 documents when I have explicitly asked to skip 1750?

Because the server side `skip()` does exactly that: it iterates over the first 1750 results and then gets 10 more (according to the limit).

As @devesh says, this is why very large pagination should be avoided since MongoDB does not make effective use of an index for `skip()` or `limit()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have hit a bulls eye , I think it is reason why mongoDB document asks us to avoid the large skips http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/ . Please have a look here It will answer your outcome . Use some other key which will be used with $gt operator will be much faster. Like Datetime stamp of last key in the page 1 then use the $get on the datetime.

> The cursor.skip() method is often expensive because it requires the server to walk from the beginning of the collection or index to get the offset or skip position before beginning to return result

Comment: I cannot use Datetime, because it is a blog. When a new post is published all existing posts, with their Datetime simply "shift". Evene if I go directly to page/200 I cannot know datetime of first post this page.